# Reshape data to new format for object detection

Tags: python, dataframe, object-detection

I have a data set in this format in dataframe

```
0--Parade/0_Parade_marchingband_1_849.jpg
2
449 330 122 149 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0--Parade/0_Parade_Parade_0_904.jpg
1
361 98 263 339 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0--Parade/0_Parade_marchingband_1_799.jpg
45
78 221 7 8   0 0 0 0 0 
78 238 14 17 2 0 0 0 0 0  
3 232 11 15 2 0 0 0 2 0 
20 215 12 16 2 0 0 0 2 0 
0--Parade/0_Parade_marchingband_1_117.jpg
23
69 359 50 36 1 0 0 0 0 1 
227 382 56 43 1 0 1 0 0 1 
296 305 44 26 1 0 0 0 0 1 
353 280 40 36 2 0 0 0 2 1 
885 377 63 41 1 0 0 0 0 1 
819 391 34 43 2 0 0 0 1 0 
727 342 37 31 2 0 0 0 0 1 
598 246 33 29 2 0 0 0 0 1 
740 308 45 33 1 0 0 0 2 1 
0--Parade/0_Parade_marchingband_1_778.jpg
35
27 226 33 36 1 0 0 0 2 0 
63 95 16 19 2 0 0 0 0 0 
64 63 17 18 2 0 0 0 0 0 
88 13 16 15 2 0 0 0 1 0 
231 1 13 13 2 0 0 0 1 0 
263 122 14 20 2 0 0 0 0 0 
367 68 15 23 2 0 0 0 0 0 
198 98 15 18 2 0 0 0 0 0 
293 161 52 59 1 0 0 0 1 0 
412 36 14 20 2 0 0 0 1 0
```

Can anyone tell me how to put these in dataframe where 1st column contain all the `.jpg` path next column contains all the coordinates but all the coordinate should be in correspondence to that `.jpg` path

eg.

```
             Column1                          coulmn2      column3
0--Parade/0_Parade_marchingband_1_849.jpg     |  2  |  449 330 122 149 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0--Parade/0_Parade_Parade_0_904.jpg           |  1  |  361 98 263 339 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0--Parade/0_Parade_marchingband_1_799.jpg     |  45 |   78 221 7 8   0 0 0 0 0 
                                              |     |   78 238 14 17 2 0 0 0 0 0  
                                              |     |   3 232 11 15 2 0 0 0 2 0 
                                              |     |   20 215 12 16 2 0 0 0 2 0
```

I have tried this

```
count1=0
count2=0
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
dict3 = {}
for i in data[0]:
    if (i.find('.jpg') == -1): 
        dict1[count1] = i
        count1+=1

    else: 
        dict2[count2] = i
        count2+=1
```

Comment: could you tell us what you've tried and/or maybe share your code?

Comment: Note: Unstructured data is a dataframe

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO, what do you mean with unstructured data is dataframe? Please include it as a code block the way it is supposed to look rather than adding comments to explain what what is. Include column headers etc. Further please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have updated the query